# Как получить рандомные значения из словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я обращался к what внутри которой лежит random.choice почему он не срабатывает?
Ведь я на вывод отправил случайное значение из словаря. И ожидал что при каждой итерации будет генерироваться случайное значение.

```
import random
test = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee']

what = {
    'a': 'a:'+random.choice(test),
    'b': 'b:'+random.choice(test)
}
for x in range(1,10):
    print(what['a'] + ' : ' + what['b'])
```

Почему не работает random в данном примере? Как исправить?:

```
Результат работы:
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ccc
```

Как тогда получить рандомное значения не кладя what в тело цикла?

Comment: Какое поведение вы ожидаете? Вы создали словарь и 9 раз отправляете его на вывод.

Comment: Почему не работает? Вы запустили random.choice два раза, он выдал результат и вы отпечатали этот результат девять раз. Между печатями вы ни разу не запускали random.choice повторно, поэтому неудивительно, что отпечатолось девять одинаковых строк.

Comment: @mkkik Я на вывод отправил случайное значение из славаря. И ожидал что при каждой итерации будет генерироваться случайное значение

Comment: @andreymai странная логика я ведь обращался к what внутри которой лежит random.choice почему он не срабатывает?

Comment: @Mikhail внутри what лежат две случайные строки, никакого random.choice там нет и никогда не было.

Comment: Но сам what (вернее, присвоение ему значений) лежит не в цикле... а цикл наружу тянуться не станет.

Comment: В python есть что то на подобии как в c randomize()?

Comment: @mkkik а как тогда получить рандомное значения не кладя what в тело цикла?

Comment: А по чему не так? `print(random.choice(test) + ' : ' + random.choice(test))`

Comment: @Mikhail, в вашем коде `random.choice` вызывается только два раза при создании словаря. Когда вы в цикле значения из словаря выводите, словарь не пересоздается, `random.choice` не вызывается заново.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что в вашем варианте словарь уже был сформирован, код отработал и там теперь лежат строки.

Вам же нужно чтобы код с рандомом срабатывал при каждом обращении по ключу, так давайте это сделаем, поместив в значение функции (лямбды).

Пример:

```
import random
test = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee']

what = {
    'a': lambda: 'a:' + random.choice(test),
    'b': lambda: 'b:' + random.choice(test)
}
for x in range(1,10):
    print(what['a']() + ' : ' + what['b']())  # Получение и вызов функции через ()
```

Вывод:

```
a:eee : b:aaa
a:ccc : b:ddd
a:ddd : b:ccc
a:ddd : b:ddd
a:eee : b:bbb
a:ddd : b:bbb
a:aaa : b:aaa
a:ccc : b:ccc
a:aaa : b:ccc
```

Answer (score 2):

> Как тогда получить рандомное значения не кладя what в тело цикла?

Как вариант:

```
import random
test = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee']

def funcWhat():
    what = {
        'a': 'a:'+random.choice(test),
        'b': 'b:'+random.choice(test)
    }
    return what

for x in range(1,10):
    print(funcWhat())
```

---

```
{'a': 'a:aaa', 'b': 'b:ddd'}
{'a': 'a:bbb', 'b': 'b:eee'}
{'a': 'a:bbb', 'b': 'b:ccc'}
{'a': 'a:bbb', 'b': 'b:aaa'}
{'a': 'a:aaa', 'b': 'b:bbb'}
{'a': 'a:bbb', 'b': 'b:bbb'}
{'a': 'a:ddd', 'b': 'b:aaa'}
{'a': 'a:bbb', 'b': 'b:eee'}
{'a': 'a:ccc', 'b': 'b:aaa'}
```

Comment: Вопрос про то "почему так", а не "сделайте мне как надо" ;-)

Comment: @Kromster   а как тогда получить рандомное значения не кладя what в тело цикла? – Mikhail

Comment: для этого стоит воспользоваться кнопкой правка и внести уточнение в вопрос, и в ответ ;-)